# Scala 2.9: is there an easy way to log all ParseResults?

Tags: parsing, scala

I've written a lexer and parser using `scala.util.parsing.combinators.Parsers`.  I have a bug in at least one of my productions, but I have so many of them that it is difficult to eyeball them to determine the problem.

What I need is a log of every attempt my Parser makes to match the input with any production; logging all the Success and Failure objects when they are instantiated would be lovely.  Unfortunately, the only way I can see to do this is to extend a lot of the basic classes provided by the library, then rewriting my massive parser to extend the new classes.

Is there an easy way to get this logging behavior?

Comment: Could you post a brief overview (with some code) of your architecture?

Comment: I don't see the point.  This is a general question about working with `Parsers` and the classes it provides, not with fixing my grammar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `log` combinator to wrap productions of your grammar. Here's the definition in `Parsers.scala`:

```
def log[T](p: => Parser[T])(name: String): Parser[T] = Parser{ in =>
  println("trying "+ name +" at "+ in)
  val r = p(in)
  println(name +" --> "+ r)
  r
}
```

Otherwise, I think you should be able to override `success` and `failure`, but it would be quite uninformative, since you won't know what production called them.